# Is there a way to get unique identifier of google chrome instance?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm looking for a way to get any permanent identifier for a browser instance like hardware id or so. I see there is a way to generate an id and store it in cookies, but if an user clears it manually, it will not be there. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: from an extension or from a web app?

Comment: No, although Microsoft would love to put one there!

Comment: @DanielA.White, from a web app.

Comment: there isn't anything like that sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There are some hacks, but the direction browsers are heading is to make it impossible to uniquely identify a device.

That's why a user can clear the cookies and that is why browsers limit access to hardware information.

Answer (score 0):

No, because that would allow websites to track users in all kinds of ways.

Microsoft used to have to install additional client-side software so they could track licensees of DRM enabled media for their old versions of Media Player, and as far as I'm aware that is still the only way to do it!

Users could still uninstall it though!